# Cannot compile MPChartExample from MPAndroidChart package in Android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have updated gradle that comes with MPChartExample to 1.0.0 and when trying to compille it below message is thrown:

```
Gradle 'MPChartExample' project refresh failed.
Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.github.mikephil.charting' in default config.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using an older version of the library? I just checked the repository and the build.gradle file of the library does not contain an "applicationId" line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `library\app` level `build.gradle` remove the `applicationId`. Libraries do not require an id. It is for applications.

Comment: Correct, it was just the problem. Removing this line from build.gradle file it works.